# Rspec error: Diff is not a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Following Ryan Bates railscast brand new to rspec.

I get

```
Guard is now watching at '/Users/thealey/Source/rpd31'
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
/Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/diff-lcs-1.1.3/lib/diff/lcs.rb:3:in `': Diff is not a module (TypeError)
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-expectations-2.6.0/lib/rspec/expectations/differ.rb:1:in `'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-expectations-2.6.0/lib/rspec/expectations.rb:9:in `'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/expecting/with_rspec.rb:1:in `'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:207:in `block in expect_with'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:202:in `each'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:202:in `expect_with'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:184:in `expectation_frameworks'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:413:in `configure_expectation_framework'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:165:in `ensure_example_groups_are_configured'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:178:in `set_it_up'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:141:in `subclass'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:129:in `describe'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:5:in `describe'
    from /Users/thealey/Source/rpd31/spec/requests/create_projects_spec.rb:3:in `'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `map'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/thealey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:11:in `block in autorun'
```

Gemfile is

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.10'


gem 'mysql2', '0.2.7'


gem "authlogic"
gem 'activesupport', '3.0.10'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'will_paginate', "~> 3.0"
gem 'calendar_date_select', :git => 'http://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select.git', :branch => 'rails3test'
gem 'bluecloth'
gem 'rdiscount'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'mail'
```

any ideas about how to troubleshoot this appreciated.

Edit: I removed commented out lines from Gemfile.

I put diff into my gemfile no change.

This is the output of bundle.

```
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.10)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)
Using activemodel (3.0.10)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.3)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.29)
Using actionpack (3.0.10)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.2)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.2.19)
Using actionmailer (3.0.10)
Using arel (2.0.10)
Using activerecord (3.0.10)
Using activeresource (3.0.10)
Using addressable (2.2.6)
Using archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
Using authlogic (3.0.3)
Using crack (0.1.8)
Using httparty (0.7.8)
Using multipart-post (1.1.3)
Using faraday (0.7.4)
Using multi_json (1.0.3)
Using oauth2 (0.5.0)
Using bitly (0.6.1)
Using bluecloth (2.1.0)
Using bson (1.3.1)
Using bson_ext (1.3.1)
Using bundler (1.0.18)
Using calendar_date_select (1.16.1) from http://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select.git (at rails3test)
Using cancan (1.6.5)
Using nokogiri (1.5.0)
Using ffi (1.0.9)
Using childprocess (0.2.2)
Using json_pure (1.6.0)
Using rubyzip (0.9.4)
Using selenium-webdriver (2.5.0)
Using xpath (0.1.4)
Using capybara (1.1.1)
Using chronic (0.6.4)
Using cocaine (0.2.0)
Using colored (1.2)
Using columnize (0.3.4)
Using daemons (1.1.4)
Using diff (0.3.6)
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3)
Using eventmachine (0.12.10)
Using factory_girl (2.1.0)
Using rdoc (3.9.4)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.10)
Using factory_girl_rails (1.2.0)
Using git_remote_branch (0.3.0)
Using googlecharts (1.6.7)
Using gravtastic (3.2.6)
Using guard (0.6.3)
Using guard-rspec (0.4.5)
Using htmldiff (0.0.1)
Using ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
Using linecache19 (0.5.12)
Using mysql2 (0.2.7)
Using net-ldap (0.2.2)
Using net-ping (1.5.0)
Using paperclip (2.4.1)
Using rails (3.0.10)
Using rdiscount (1.6.8)
Using ri_cal (0.8.8)
Using riddle (1.4.0)
Using rspec-core (2.6.4)
Using rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
Using rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
Using rspec (2.6.0)
Using rspec-rails (2.6.1)
Using ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
Using ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
Using seed_dump (0.3.4)
Using thin (1.2.11)
Using thinking-sphinx (2.0.1)
Using time_diff (0.2.1)
Using will_paginate (3.0.pre)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: have you tried to install gem for Diff?

Comment: Feel free to delete lines that aren't relevant, too, like the gems you're not including.

Answer (score 1):

I had the identical issue.  In my case I had a model class called Diff (defined in diff.rb) which led to the issue.  I've renamed my class/module and all is well now.  I'm somewhat disappointed that this sort of namespace collision could occur.

Other users have also encountered issues with collisions originating from other gems (eg: https://github.com/sunaku/tork/issues/3).  If I were troubleshooting the issue, I'd go to your gem directory (use bundle show for any one of your gems to find where they live) and run

`find . -name diff.rb`

That should tell you all of the libraries that contain a diff.rb file.  I'd be looking for one of the more obscure/less actively maintained gems to be the culprit.  You'll likely need to find an alternative gem (or contribute a fix the offending gem!) to fix the issue.